# Is the basic point of Book of Job that God is too intelligent for a human to understand, and whatever he decides actually has a good overall purpose?

Tags: nature-of-god, good-and-evil, job

I've tried to read "Book of Jobs". I simply don't have the peace of mind and "practical time" to do it, just like with many other things.

However, I've watched and read multiple different summaries of it. None of these spell it out in a clear manner, but from what I can tell, the basic "explanation" is:

1. God is good, no matter what he does.
2. Us humans cannot possibly understand what He plans, and even though it appears like it, his actions are actually not evil after all. You just don't see it (yet?).
3. There is no point in trying to understand His actions, because we are simply *unable* to comprehend it, so just believe that He is good and ignore whatever injustice or horror you witness or are subjected to.

Just like with the concept of "free will", which is fundamentally, logically impossible for a creature who didn't "pick their own biology" beginning from some kind of neutral state, I have a major problem with this explanation of God's apparent evilness: "You just can't understand it!"

There are many things I don't understand in detail, such as advanced physics. However, I can still reason about them at some level. It is possible for a scientist who is very intelligent to explain intricate concepts on a "high level" to somebody like me; I don't need to be as smart as them or spend 30 years in a lab to understand the basic idea of how a man-made contraption can go from here to some distant planet. The same ought to be true for this; maybe there is a highly complex reason for God doing what he does, but then I wish to know about that reason, simplified to a point where I, a stupid human, can comprehend it. Not just "you can't understand it, period".

My back is hurting beyond words as I'm typing this. I'm all alone, with nothing but pain and misery in my life. The worst bullies -- truly evil people -- who I grew up with are now all living in mansions (literal mansions) with beautiful wives and kids and careers. A mentally weaker person than I would've committed suicide long ago in my situation. Frankly, I mostly don't because I'm too much of a coward. I'm going to be forced to endure this existence until I die from natural causes or somebody murders me. Or maybe until God regrets treating me this way and finally starts being nice to me.

It is not possible for me to praise God as being good, because he really doesn't seem to be to me. That he appears to be to others, who are far less deserving, just further reinforces this perception. To then hear that I'm just a stupid human who doesn't "get it" feels incredibly insulting, so I really hope that this is not really the point of Book of Job.

What is the basic point of the Book of Job? Is it simply that "if you believe, against all rhyme and reason, that God is actually good, no matter how much proof you get of the opposite, he will eventually be good to you because you believed"?

If this is the case, I find God's reasoning to be very strange. I literally don't get it.

Comment: Rather than provide an answer for you in this open forum, I'd rather provide an answer one on one. If you look up my bio page, you will find my email address. I have a feeling your question will be closed, not because it's a bad question but because you seem to be asking for more than just an interpretation of a passage of Scripture. Moreover, you're asking more than one question and some of them are of a personal nature. So shoot me an email. I'll copy and paste your question onto a file and continue crafting an answer. Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Please see the following 3 links https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44280/is-god-being-deceitful/44281#44281, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/50504/why-did-jobs-siblings-assume-it-was-the-lord-who-brought-on-all-the-trouble/50524#50524, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/to-whom-does-righteous-refer-in-psalm-145/38065#38065 The purpose is multi fold but not random nor purposeless and definitely not because God had some itching whim to prove a point. Job was guilty of an extremely subtle sin upright people are very susceptible towards.